# WooCommerce - disable postcode validation

Tags: wordpress, validation, woocommerce, postal-code

Does anybody know how to disable the Postcode validation on the checkout page in WooCommerce?

My country is set up as Switzerland, but I want also people from Austria and Germany allow to order.

So when I enter a German Postcode with 5 digits (in Switzerland there are only 4), the shop says it's an invalid postcode. (but in the settings I allowed every country).

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers don't seem to address the question! The postcode is still a required field, it's matter of whether other postcodes can be allowed that WooCommerce is saying is wrong.

For a checkout I'm building I've used this filter to allow any postcode to be considered valid regardless of country/postcode given.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_validate_postcode' , 'mycode_override_postcode_check', 99, 3 );
function mycode_override_postcode_check( $valid, $postcode, $country ) {
    return true;
}
```

You can change that `return true;` for more complex code logic that reviews the postcode and country, this can help if your version of WooCommerce doesn't cover new postcode/zip code rules and you need them to be accepted.
Source: https://github.com/EloxZ/wordpresscrm/blob/main/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-validation.php#L123

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to the functions.php file should work:

```
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) 
{
    unset( $address_fields['postcode'] );
    return $address_fields;
}
```

EDIT:

```
// Hook into the checkout fields (shipping & billing)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Hook into the default fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );



function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) 
{
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] );
    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] );

    return $fields;
}

function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) 
{
    unset( $address_fields['postcode'] );

    return $address_fields;
}
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) 
{
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Comment: I added the code to the functions.php but unfortunately it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Nevermind :) But now I don't see any postcode field at all... It should be actually visible but I just want to be able to type in any kind of number. Sorry if my post was not clear.

Comment: Still saying the postcode is not valid :( Even if the field is not a mandatory field now... Maybe you have another idea ???

Comment: That should do it. Maybe you have some plugin that is effecting that?

Comment: The only Plugin I use for WooCommerce is "Min/Max Quantities" which I already deactivated. Unfortunately, still the same issue.

I guess there is a kind of pattern matching defined for the postcode somewhere... Guess I have to keep trying. But thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: The above answer removes the postcode, whereas op wants to disable the validation only. I've been looking for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't actually find a simple code solution for this one but I noticed that if I set

```
WooCommerce > Preferences > General > Geolocate address
```

it will work (if settings are set to "Sell to all countries", in my case)

Answer (score 1):

This code only removes validation of address fields in my-account page, what you need:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields',
   'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

function custom_override_default_address_fields($address_fields)
{
    $address_fields['postcode']['validate'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

for billing and shipping:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'remove_postcode_validation', 99 );

function remove_postcode_validation( $fields ) {

unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['validate']);
unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['validate']);

return $fields;
}
```

Also i think with removing "validate-required" class in wc-template-function.php, this feature will be deactivated (no test).

Sorry for bad English and hope this solutions solve your problem.